# DBFlow lost the data in String type

Tags: string, sqlite, dbflow

DBFlow Version:4.2.4

Bug or Feature Request:lost the long string data

Description: i have a long json string,and i inserted the bean without any wrong,but i read it from the database,the value is null.
my string like this as follow:
https://github.com/agrosner/DBFlow/issues/1695

and my code is :

PlotCanvasBean plotCanvasBean = new PlotCanvasBean(plotWithGeo);

```
                plotCanvasBean.setLoginId(AppManager.getInstance().getUserSession().getUid());
                plotCanvasBean.setCreateTime(new Date());
                plotCanvasBean.setUUID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                plotCanvasBean.setPlotId(param.getId());

                plotCanvasBean.insert();

                List<PlotCanvasBean> plotCanvasBeans1 = SQLite.select()
                        .from(PlotCanvasBean.class)
                        .where(PlotCanvasBean_Table.id.isNotNull())
                        .queryList();
```

and the column declare as a String
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMYxE.png)

screenshot as follow:
the bean insert into the database

the bean read from the database